# UML "direct substate" vs "transitively nested substate"

Tags: uml, state, finite-state-machine

I am reading through [Wikipedia's page on UML state machines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Hierarchically_nested_states). I don't understand where it says:

> A nested state is called a direct substate when it is not contained by
>   any other state; otherwise, it is referred to as a transitively nested
>   substate.

I want to understand the difference between a "direct substate" and a "transitively nested substate". The quoted sentence says one is contained by another state, and the other is not. But if both are nested, then surely both are contained by another state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Direct substate** is a one level substate of a state
- **Transitively nested substate** is a substate of a substate (any levels down)

Consider this diagram:

[image: StateNesting]

For *active* state **direct substates** are

- filing
- warming up
- washing
- emptying

while **transitively nested substate** are

- rotating left
- rotating right
- inceasing speed (substate of rotating left)
- full speed rotation (substate of rotating left)
- inceasing speed (substate of rotating right)
- full speed rotation (substate of rotating right)

For *washing* state **direct substates** are

- rotating left
- rotating right

while **transitively nested substate** are

- inceasing speed (substate of rotating left)
- full speed rotation (substate of rotating left)
- inceasing speed (substate of rotating right)
- full speed rotation (substate of rotating right)

etc.

*idle* has neither direct nor transitively added substates.