# Hierarchical state machine. Is there a term for the deepest nested state in a state configuration?

Tags: terminology, state, finite-state-machine

A flat state machine has one active state.  In a hierarchical state machine (HSM), if the HSM is in a child state, it's also in it's parent state.  So, an active state configuration of an HSM consists of multiple states which form a tree.  If the HSM doesn't have orthogonal regions, the tree simplifies to a list.

Is there an accepted term for the deepest nested state(s) in an active state configuration?

If it helps clarify the question, here's an example of a simple HSM without orthogonal regions.  Active state configuration is shown with thick outline.

#### State chart perspective

[image: Example state chart for an HSM. Active state configuration shown with thick outline.] ([source](http://prolifictec.com/blog/2015/09/chain-of-responsibility-pattern-in-hierarchical-state-machine.html))

#### State hierarchy perspective

[image: HSM state hierarchy. Active state configuration shown with thick outline.] ([source](http://prolifictec.com/blog/2015/09/chain-of-responsibility-pattern-in-hierarchical-state-machine.html))

Comment: It's called "The deepest nested state(s) in an active state configuration."  Given that you're using a tree as a data structure, I suppose you could also call such a state a "leaf state."

Comment: @Robert  "*The deepest nested state(s) in the active configuration*" does get the point across.  I'm hoping for something shorter, thought.  "*Leaf active states*" crossed my mind too.  My reservation about "leaf" is that it may be confusing in cases when deepest nested state isn't a leaf state in the overall state hierarchy.

Comment: remotely related question about HSM terminology: [“direct substate” vs “transitively nested substate”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334108/134647)